# In this code how can I add a DatePicker method for the user to search for ( Start_date ) and ( end_date )

Tags: php, yii

This code is in view, with him I can search only the dates coming from the database , I would add a method where you do the research ( Start_date ) and ( end_date ).

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => ''],
                    'columns' => [
                        //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                        [
                        'attribute' => 'date',
                            'content' => function(SaleItems $model, $key, $index, $column) {
                                return $model->sale->date;
                                },
                            'header' => 'DATA',
                        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a datepicker as the "filter" property of the column definition.  See http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/318/using-cjuidatepicker-for-cgridview-filter/